# React Router. How to prevent crashing whole app when have any error on of the container(page)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, jsx

I have code like this

[Simple code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vgkoOBELr)

For example if About page have syntax error whole application crashing.

1. How to handle this situation ?
2. Should routes must be in a separate(configuration) file or it's ok when they are in index.js file
3. What is the best practice for using React Router in real huge
   project using browserHistory? May be some template or examples on git repo.

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43491059/edit) your question to (1) fix the originally linked code-snippet, (2) add any additional information you think is necessary, instead of using comments.

Comment: Clearly saying you should not be able to build application with syntax error inside. In this case i would suggest to review the app delivery workflow.

Comment: @ArkadyB  it's just an example. Сould be any mistake that you haven't thought of,  but it should not break the whole application

Answer (score 4):

Consider using an ErrorBoundary component that you define to contain your error and display a friendly error message. This is the recommended way if you're using React 16: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <MyComponent/>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

See demo by Dan Abramov: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0010

The advantage of this method is that you get to choose who many levels of the component hierarchy you want the error to bubble up.